# Only read first line of a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file named "paintingJobs".  The data looks like this:

```
E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0
E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290
E5343,21/09/2015,C104,730,N,0
E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180
```

I have written a program that only finds the first entry but cannot find any data beyond the first line (I think it is to do with Python including /n in front of the username)  The program looks like this.

```
def ASearch():
    print("Option A: Search for an estimate")
    print("Please enter the estimate number: ")
    estimateNumber = str(input())
    file = open("paintingJobs.txt", "r")
    paintJobs = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    length = len(paintJobs)
    paintData = []
    for line in paintJobs:        
        estNumber, estDate, CustID, FinalTotal, Status, AmountPaid =      line.split(",")
        if estimateNumber == estNumber:            
            print("Estimate number: ", estNumber)
            print("Customer ID: ", CustID)
            options()#this is a function in a for a different part of the program that works fine
        else:
            print("You have entered an incorrect estimate number; please try again")
            ASearch()
```

How do I get the program to read (and return the values of) the second entry in the list E.G. E5342  (any help would be appreciated greatly)

Comment: Put your text in notepad++ and turn on View->Show Symbols->Show All Characters. It could be that you're using a different line ending. E.g. '\n' vs '\r\n'

Comment: Found the answer I needed to index the entries